# Objects in a list needs to access parent list properties

Tags: delphi

This is a design question for Delphi.

An Object A contains a set of variables and at the same time stores a list of Objects of type B. Objects of type B need to access the common variables in the container Object A. One option is for Objects B to hold a reference to the container Object A but this seems to result in storing the reference to A as a TObject and casing each time to Object A in order to access the variables. Any other possible design solutions?

```
Object B
  // Possible solution
  ref to Object A

Object A
  x : integer
  list of B
```

Each B needs access to x

Comment: What's stopping you from doing it? This is very trivial. Just declare a variable and assign that variable to its parent when you create it.

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to have to cast each time. Anyway the answer occurred me minutes after I posted the question but David Heffernan posted the answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a forward type declaration:

```
type
  TContainer = class; // forward declaration

  TItem = class
  private
    FContainer: TContainer;
    ....
  end;

  TContainer = class
  private
    // list of items
  end;
```

The forward declaration can be either the container or the item, it doesn't much matter which.

Read all about this in the docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes

Comment: After I posted the question, as is typical the answer came to me. The moral of the story is, don't just think about what the answer might be but in my case draw out the problem on paper and the solution jumps out. Nevertheless it is worth reminding readers, including myself, about forward declarations.