# How to define a template for generic collection item?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to define my own items type for a generic list. All items need to have an `owner` property.

```
type 
  TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem: class> = class(TObjectList<TGenericCollectionItem>)
  protected
    procedure Notify(const Value: TGenericCollectionItem; Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>); virtual;
  end;

  TGenericCollectionItem = class
  private
    FOwner: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>;  //another class can change this value if it was declared in the same unit
  protected
    function GetOwner: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>; virtual;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    property Owner: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem> read GetOwner;
  end;

implementation

{ TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem> }
procedure TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>.Assign(
  Source: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>);
begin
  AddRange(Source.ToArray);
end;

procedure TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>.Notify(
  const Value: TGenericCollectionItem; Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  inherited;

  if (Action = cnAdded) then
  begin
    OutputDebugString(PChar(Value.ClassName)); // Debug Output: THandingItem Process GenericCollection.exe (2424)
    OutputDebugString(PChar(Self.ClassName));  // Debug Output: THandingList Process GenericCollection.exe (2424)
//    Value.FOwner := Self;  // Error: [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(46): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'FOwner'
//    (Value as TGenericCollectionItem).FOwner := Self;   // Error: [dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(46): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'FOwner'
//    (Value as TGenericCollectionItem<T>).FOwner := Self;   // Undeclared identifier 'T'
  end;
end;
```

When I'm trying to change `FOwner` value the compiler says that `FOwner` is undeclared identifier. `THandingList` inherits from `TGenericCollection`. `THandingItem` inherits from `TGenericCollectionItem`.

What I'm doing wrong?
[Sample project](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B07M5qigwELceVp6dmNJOEF6ZjA/edit?usp=sharing)

---

UPD: `TGenericCollectionItem` changed in code sample.

---

Console app:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem: class> = class(TObjectList<TGenericCollectionItem>)
  protected
    procedure Notify(const Value: TGenericCollectionItem; Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
  end;

  TGenericCollectionItem = class
  public
    Owner: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>;
  end;

  procedure TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>.Notify(
    const Value: TGenericCollectionItem; Action: TCollectionNotification);
  begin
    inherited;

    if (Action = cnAdded) then
      Value.Owner := Self;
  end;

var
  GenericCollectionItem: TGenericCollectionItem;
  GenericCollection: TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>;
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    GenericCollection := TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem>.Create;
    try
      GenericCollectionItem := TGenericCollectionItem.Create;
      GenericCollection.Add(GenericCollectionItem);
    finally
      GenericCollection.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: That's because you've declared the `FOwner` in the `TGenericCollectionItem<T: class>` class, not in the base `TGenericCollectionItem` class (where it's not yet known). Besides, it's read only at this time.

Comment: What is the generic parameter to TGenericCollectionItem meant to do? Surely that is just wrong. There's also a fatal flaw in your design. An item can be a member of two lists. Which one is the owner?

Comment: @TLama OK. I've changed `TGenericCollectionItem` class (see code in question). But compiler still says the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know who will be the owner. May be the last one. I'm trying to implement `TCollection` and `TCollectionItem` functionality in generics. `TCollection` and `TCollectionItem`are in the `System.Classes` unit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan check the question update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh this is confusing. You've used `TGenericCollectionItem` as both a generic parameter name, and the name of a type. In `TGenericCollection` code the name `TGenericCollectionItem` refers to the generic type parameter rather than the class of the same name. And all that you know about `TGenericCollectionItem` the generic parameter is that it is a class. That is, it derives from `TObject`. And so has no member named `Owner`, or indeed `FOwner`.

Change

```
TGenericCollection<TGenericCollectionItem: class>
```

to

```
TGenericCollection<T: TGenericCollectionItem>
```

Note that you will likely need to forward declare `TGenericCollectionItem`.

**Update:** Argh, a forward declaration won't work when one of the mutually referential classes is generic, due to a design deficiency of Delphi generics. See [How to set a forward declaration with generic types under Delphi 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055742/how-to-set-a-forward-declaration-with-generic-types-under-delphi-2010)

Comment: Thanks. Seems that will work. But now I can't make a forward declaration of `TGenericCollectionItem`. Type 'TGenericCollectionItem' is not yet completely defined.

Comment: I'll make a new one question.

Comment: Don't make a new question. Read my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474503/objects-in-a-list-needs-to-access-parent-list-properties

Comment: It's not the same. The right solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055742/how-to-set-a-forward-declaration-with-generic-types-under-delphi-2010

Comment: Yeah I realised after posting. Generics kick you. I actually solve this problem differently from the answer there, but there you go.